# Angular, Ag-Grid, Error with Jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, ag-grid

I am using exactly same datepicker function as shown in the example code on [Ag-Grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/)

```
getDatePicker() {
  function Datepicker() {}
  Datepicker.prototype.init = function(params) {
    this.eInput = document.createElement("input");
    this.eInput.value = params.value;
    $(this.eInput).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

  };
  //blah blah
  return Datepicker;
}
```

However, when I enabled editing for date columns, I got an error for `$(this.eInput)` line:

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery__(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Seems something wrong with the Jquery package that I am using? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I've same issue, and still trying to understand how to solve it.

Did u find any work around yet?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is , NOT to use jquery with angular.

For your problem, maybe Datepicker is not initialized properly. It looks like it will add some function on DOM. But you rewrite the init function, and you require itself is initialized during init.

Comment: Okay...just wondering how and why it works with Angular in [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#datepicker-cell-editing-example) in Ag-Grid official documentation?

Comment: I will still say, not to use jquery with angular. You should learn to manage  the DOM and action in angular way.